# How to access the webresource controls from another html webresource on CRM 2016 Form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2016

I have two html webresources in my customer form, one contains a multitab and second contains some tiles, designed using bootstrap and JQuery for events. Want to initiate a Click event of tab exist on first webresource on the click of tiles exist on second webresource.

I have prepared the script on simple html page first all code is working there but not on crm form.

1. How can I access the tab controls using JQuery from first webresource?
2. I have written some scripts on each html webresources, can I use the same script/function from another html webresource?

**Webresource_1**

```
  //html

    <div class="row">     
         <ul id="tab_container_01" class="nav nav-tabs">
         <li id="tab_cases"><a id="ahref_cases" href="#">Cases</a></li>
         </ul>
    </div>
    //script
    //Following script is working fine on the same page
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $("ul.nav-tabs").on("click", "li", function () {
        var selectedTabText = ($(this).find("a").text());
        var tabs = window.parent.Xrm.Page.ui.tabs;
        //Some toggle script
    });

</script>
```

**Webresource_2**

```
//html

<div class="panel">           
    <div> Open Cases </div>
</div>

//script
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".panel").on("click", "div", function () {

// following not working on crm form
$("#tab_cases").addClass('active');
$("#tab_cases").parent().siblings().removeClass('active'); //length 0, id not detecting

//window.parent.$("#tab_cases").parent().siblings().removeClass('active');

/* trigger click event on the li */
//trying to use function written on webresource_1 script

$("#tab_cases").closest("ul.nav-tabs li").trigger('click'); //*Not Triggering*
});
</script>
```

Comment: [Xrm.Page.ui control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266(v=crm.8).aspx#BKMK_webResource) suggests that this should be possible using `Xrm.Page.getControl(arg).getObject()` which will return the respective IFRAME of your WebResource. (Didn't try myself yet)

Comment: Yes... You are right, I can see that..after finding the object how to access further ? I can see the object using following script : window.parent.Xrm.Page.getControl("WebResource_Tab").getObject();

Comment: As I said I didn't try myself, but you should be able to access the DOM from there on. Best shot will be inspecting the result of `getObject()` using the debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Although, technically since you are all within CRM, and you won't have any Cross Domain Scripting issues, this may be a little over kill, you could use [Window.Post](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) Message from Frame1, to communicate to the CRM form, and then have it communicate to Frame 2.  This would also mean that your scripts wouldn't have to be dependent on the DOM of each, other subscribe to the same interface for posting/receiving messages.